# Wave packet - phase vs group velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, dispersion, phase-velocity

So, I've been revising QM recently and the concept of [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) vs [phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) velocity has me confused.

Let's say we have a wave packet. As quoted in Griffiths, "...A wave packet is a superposition of sinusoidal functions whose amplitude is modulated by an envelope...". If I understand this correctly, the equation for a wave packet can be rewritten as:

$\psi(x,t) = A(x-v_gt)*f(x-v_pt) \tag{1} $

where $A$ is the "envelope" function, $f$ represents the underlying "ripples", and $v_g$ and $v_p$ represent group and phase velocities respectively.

It is also known that the speed of the wave packet is equal to the absolute value of group velocity, which implies that:

$\psi(x,t) = \psi(x-v_gt,0) \tag{2} $

Using (1) and (2), we can write,

$\psi(x-v_gt,0) = A(x-v_gt)*f(x-v_gt) \tag{3} $

Which means that,

$A(x-v_gt)*f(x-v_pt)= A(x-v_gt)*f(x-v_gt) \tag{4} $

Implying that $v_p = v_g$, which is only a special case, not a generality.

Where am I going wrong?

From a less quantitative perspective, how does a particular value of $\psi$ move along the x-axis at the speed of the contributing envelope function, when the factors (the envelope and the sinusoidal function) that create this value through multiplication, move across the x-axis at different speeds?

Let's take the value of $\psi$ at time $t = 0$ for some $x = x_0$ and observe it's movement along x over time interval $dt$. Then, a point on the envelope function moves a distance of $v_gdt$ along the x axis whereas the sinusoidal function moves a distance of $v_pdt$.

This would mean the point on the envelope function meets a new point on the sinusoidal function, creating a new value of $\psi$ (which isn't equal to the value of $\psi$ at $x = x_0$, which it should be because we claim that the wave packet moves at the speed of the absolute value of group velocity). Sorry, couldn't find an easier/more intuitive way to write this.

Comment: You statement $\psi(x,t) = \psi(x-v_gt,0)$ is incorrect. It's true that $A(x,t) = A(x-v_gt,0)$ but that's all. There is no such restriction on $f(x,t)$.

Comment: But doesn't $f(x,t)$ move at a particular velocity, allowing us to write that?

Comment: [Have a look at the animated GIFs here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) to see an illustration o the motion.

Comment: So, while $\psi(x,t) \ne \psi(x-v_gt, 0)$, the following still holds true for the probability density function, $|\psi(x,t)|^2 = |\psi(x-v_gt,0)|^2 $. Implying that the wave function doesn't move along the x-axis at a proper velocity, but the probability density function moves at the group velocity. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems a good summary of the situation.

Comment: That makes things much clearer. Thanks a lot!